# Integrating .NET Application with IMail

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, calendar

We use IMail. I am writing a diary/calendar system and ideally would like to integrate with the users IMail calendar.

I need to check for appointments, meetings etc in the users calendar before booking appointments. Would like to display a calendar view using data from Imail. Is this possible, if so can anyone suggest a starting point, reading material to do this.

Comment: A small start: http://forums.ipswitch.com/Topic40236-10-1.aspx#bm52881

Comment: http://forums.ipswitch.com/Topic48168-10-1.aspx?Highlight=API

Comment: and finally http://forums.ipswitch.com/Topic47526-10-1.aspx?Highlight=API

Comment: @Joshua - thanks for the help, looks like I can integrate with my app